# Does type [string()] cover empty list?

Tags: erlang, dialyzer

When defining a type which will be a list of strings but can also be an empty list, do I have to define both cases like this:

```
-type my_type() :: [string()] | [].
```

or is this enough:

```
-type my_type() :: [string()].
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, `[string()]` includes the empty list so using `-type my_type() :: [string()].` is fine if you want to include empty lists.

> Because lists are commonly used, they have shorthand type notations. The types `list(T)` and `nonempty_list(T)` have the shorthands `[T]` and `[T,...]`, respectively. The only difference between the two shorthands is that `[T]` can be an empty list but `[T,...]` cannot.

[Source](http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/typespec.html#id78676)